# Use browsers built in validation of the required attribute in combination with Angular 5?

Tags: css, html, angular, required

I am building a single application using Angular 5. I create a form using the Reactive Forms of Angular.

In the input I use the HTML5 validation attribute required. When I submit the form and input is left empty, I would expect the browsers built in validation of the input:

[image: expected browser validation using required attribute]

But nothing.

Is Angular suppressing the browsers built in behavior of validating the required input field? Can I activate it and still using FormBuilder?

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-system-create',
  templateUrl: './system-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./system-create.component.scss']
})
export class SystemCreateComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      shortName: ''
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("on submit");
  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-element">
    <label>short name</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="shortName" type="text" placeholder="e.g. SYS" id="systemForm_shortName" required>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Speichern</button>
</form>
```

Comment: is this behavior continues if you change "onSubmit()" to "onSubmit(e){ e.preventDefault()"?

Comment: I tried with:`(ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"` and `onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}` but still no validation by browser.

Comment: interesting, look on this plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/vinObnN27m6Ogrnuaws8?p=preview, here i can see validtion

Comment: looks like the   import of ReactiveFormsModule get it disabled

Comment: Yes you are right,  import of ReactiveFormsModule  seems to disable that. Hm, any idea how to still have the native browser validations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try adding the attribute `ngNativeValidate` in your form element to prevent Angular from adding the [`novalidate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) html attribute. As explained in the Angular [`NgNoValidate`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_no_validate_directive.ts) directive documentation.

> If you want to use native validation with Angular forms, just add `ngNativeValidate` attribute